# Greasemonkey script ignores elements appended to table rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I use jQuery to append some `<th>` and `<td>` elements to a number of rows in a table:

```
$(selector).filter(function () {
    //jQuery finds some cells, evaluates them and generates new cell content
    $(this).parent().append('<td>' + FormattedDate + '</td>');
});        

//Some code here generates counts

for(var i = column_count; i > header_count; i--) {
    $('.result_table tr:first').append("<th>test</th>");
}
```

Then, I load [this Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/25406) that is supposed to make the whole table sortable. However, the Greasemonkey script only makes sortable the columns that were part of the table before I added the cells with jQuery. How can I make it work on all the columns?

Comment: Please don't waste your time telling me I should just do the adding of the cells inside the Greasemonkey script. That is not the question that I'm asking.

Comment: Most greasemonkey scripts load at page load time.  What are you doing to ensure that the greasemonkey script initializes itself only after your code has modified the table?

Comment: Does your jQuery run all at once, one time, at `$(document).ready`, or is it an intermittent, AJAX affair?  Is this a page you control, or another GM script that's adding the counts?

Comment: I run all the JavaScript provided in the example at `$(document).ready`. It's on a page I control. Is there a way to "tell" the Greasemonkey script to wait until JavaScript on the page has executed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without changing the Greasemonkey script.  But, in this case it's fairly easy because the target page just changes the table once and does it `$(document).ready` (Nominally `DOMContentLoaded`).

So, if you set the Greasemonkey script to run at window `load`, then it will run after the table has been modified.

For [this particular script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/25406), just change the last lines from:

```
var allTables = window.document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName ("TABLE");
CODEBOX.forEach (allTables, function (table){
    CODEBOX.tabsorter.processTable (table);
} );
```

To:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function () {
    var allTables = window.document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName ("TABLE");
    CODEBOX.forEach (allTables, function (table){
        CODEBOX.tabsorter.processTable (table);
    } );
} );
```